# Сильное кеширование на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Собрали сайт на вордпрессе, но столкнулись с проблемой: он чрезмерно кешируется. То есть любая правка в верстке требует захода через инкогнито, не обновляется в браузере. Сторонних плагинов (типа рокета) не установлено. В чем может быть проблема?

Проверили наличие проблемных плагинов.

Comment: В настройках кеширования. Ваш КЭП.